# Has anyone tried to make an aircraft using centripetal force to hover or fly or is it not going to happen

Tags: airspace

[image].        Air craft testing  might be the idea we need

Comment: Pretty sure that's an "edited" video.

Comment: This question is very unclear and the attached unattributed image isn't obviously related to the title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you explain what you mean by "using centripetal force to hover or fly"? There's no obvious way that centripetal force could be used to make something hover or fly, so the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Related to this post by any chance? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/is-there-any-developments-on-centrifugal-thrust

Answer (score 7):

There have been various proposals at various times to try to use things like centripetal/centrifugal force, impact vs. rebound, and various other methods to extract a net force from the movement of mass.  All have failed, because momentum is conserved, and for the same reason, this method of propulsion will never work.